# Flutter Scroll List Over Header

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I Want To Scrll My List Like This

[image]

[image]

```
class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget   {
  const TestScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    AppController appController = Provider.of<AppController>(context);
    HomeController homeController = Provider.of<HomeController>(context);
    String selectedCategory = homeController.selectedCategory;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        //height: 450,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(

            image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/home_header.png'),
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,

             repeat: ImageRepeat.repeatY,

        )),
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
            flexibleSpace: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
              child: ChiscoAppbar(
                icon: MENU,
                iconAlignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                title: 'خانه',
                onClick: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/account');
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  height: 200,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      const Expanded(
                        flex: 3,
                        child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: ChiscoText(
                              text: 'دستگاه‌های هوشمند چیسکو',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16,
                            )),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: const [
                                HeaderItem(
                                  titleText: 'کنترلر',
                                  icon: COOLER,
                                  counterText: '2',
                                ),
                                HeaderItem(
                                  titleText: 'سه راهی',
                                  icon: SOCKET,
                                  counterText: '2',
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          )),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                  top: homeController.customPixel+20 ,
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Styles.backGroundColor,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  )),
              NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
                onNotification: homeController.scrollNotification,
                // color: Styles.backGroundColor,
                child: CustomScrollView(
                  slivers: [
                    SliverToBoxAdapter(
                        child: Container(
                      height: 200,
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                    )),
                    SliverPersistentHeader(
                      delegate: OnTapHeader(),
                      floating: false,
                      pinned: true,
                    ),
                    SliverToBoxAdapter(
                        child: Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 8, 20, 10),
                      height: 30,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount: appController.listOfDevicesCategory.length,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          primary: true,
                          addSemanticIndexes: false,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            String category =
                                appController.listOfDevicesCategory[index];
                            return CategoryListItem(
                              isSelected: selectedCategory == category,
                              category: category,
                            );
                          }),
                    )),
                    DeviceGridList()
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),

          floatingActionButton:Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
              child: const ChiscoSpeedDial()),
          floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.startDocked,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

I want to the white part scroll over the blue part until bottom of my app bar Like to screenshots

if i use Slivers The white part collapse the Blue part .

next Challenge that i have is in normal State the white part in on top of blue.

how can i do these??

im sorry if my question is not so clear :)

**////UPDATE Question//////////**

I used `DraggableScrollableSheet` for my lists and inside this i used Column but it dosent work right

Result of using `DraggableScrollableSheet`

[image]

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    AppController appController = Provider.of<AppController>(context);
    HomeController homeController = Provider.of<HomeController>(context);
    String selectedCategory = homeController.selectedCategory;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        //height: 450,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/home_header.png'),
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        )),
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
            flexibleSpace: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
              child: ChiscoAppbar(
                icon: MENU,
                iconAlignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                title: 'خانه',
                onClick: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/account');
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  height: 200,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      const Expanded(
                        flex: 3,
                        child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: ChiscoText(
                              text: 'دستگاه‌های هوشمند چیسکو',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16,
                            )),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: const [
                                HeaderItem(
                                  titleText: 'کنترلر',
                                  icon: COOLER,
                                  counterText: '2',
                                ),
                                HeaderItem(
                                  titleText: 'سه راهی',
                                  icon: SOCKET,
                                  counterText: '2',
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          )),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
                  expand: true,
                  minChildSize: 0.70,
                  maxChildSize: 0.95,
                  initialChildSize: 0.70,
                  builder: (context, scrollController) {
                    return Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blue[100],
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(25))),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        controller: scrollController,
                        child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

                            children: [
                            ListHandlerView(),
                            Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 8, 20, 10),
                              height: 30,
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                  itemCount:
                                      appController.listOfDevicesCategory.length,
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  primary: true,
                                  addSemanticIndexes: false,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    String category = appController
                                        .listOfDevicesCategory[index];
                                    return CategoryListItem(
                                      isSelected: selectedCategory == category,
                                      category: category,
                                    );
                                  }),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.blue[100],
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                      topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                                      topRight: Radius.circular(25))),
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                
                                itemCount: 25,
                                controller: scrollController,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

                                  return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          floatingActionButton: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
              child: const ChiscoSpeedDial()),
          floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.startDocked,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CustomScrollView` with `SliverAppBar(expandedHeight`

Here the bottom will be always visible, I assume you need it for top row.

```dart
  return SafeArea(
      child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: 200,
            pinned: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40),
              child: ColoredBox(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Container(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(12),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  height: 40,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate.fixed(
              [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(12),
                      ),
                      color: Colors.white),
                  height: 1140,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried before it makes blue header Collapesing 
I Want the white part Scroll Overt The Blue Header

Comment: try update widget .

Comment: My concern was using bottom appBar to show category as shown on UI.

Answer (score 2):

Try DraggableScrollableSheet

```dart
DraggableScrollableSheet(
          builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.blue[100],
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: scrollController,
                itemCount: 25,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
                },
              ),
```

You can also specify it's maxChildSize which by default is 1 which means it will scroll to the top of the screen

**EDIT**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    AppController appController = Provider.of<AppController>(context);
    HomeController homeController = Provider.of<HomeController>(context);
    String selectedCategory = homeController.selectedCategory;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        //height: 450,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/home_header.png'),
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        )),
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
            flexibleSpace: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
              child: ChiscoAppbar(
                icon: MENU,
                iconAlignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                title: 'خانه',
                onClick: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/account');
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  height: 200,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      const Expanded(
                        flex: 3,
                        child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: ChiscoText(
                              text: 'دستگاه‌های هوشمند چیسکو',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16,
                            )),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: const [
                                HeaderItem(
                                  titleText: 'کنترلر',
                                  icon: COOLER,
                                  counterText: '2',
                                ),
                                HeaderItem(
                                  titleText: 'سه راهی',
                                  icon: SOCKET,
                                  counterText: '2',
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          )),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
                  expand: true,
                  minChildSize: 0.70,
                  maxChildSize: 0.95,
                  initialChildSize: 0.70,
                  builder: (context, scrollController) {
                    return Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blue[100],
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(25))),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        controller: scrollController,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            ListHandlerView(),
                            Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 8, 20, 10),
                              height: 30,
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                  itemCount: appController
                                      .listOfDevicesCategory.length,
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  primary: true,
                                  addSemanticIndexes: false,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    String category = appController
                                        .listOfDevicesCategory[index];
                                    return CategoryListItem(
                                      isSelected: selectedCategory == category,
                                      category: category,
                                    );
                                  }),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.blue[100],
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                      topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                                      topRight: Radius.circular(25))),
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: 25,
                                controller: scrollController,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          floatingActionButton: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
              child: const ChiscoSpeedDial()),
          floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.startDocked,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

There is a single child scroll view and a list view as a child of it.. Add physics to ListView and it should work as expected.

Comment: Use it in Stack Or Where?

Comment: Yeah in a stack

Comment: I Want add Multiple Items in its child , But When i Use Column it dosent show any thing also give me error 'Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.'

Comment: Thts because an expanded or flexible is used in a column widget.. also add mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min to the column and shrinkWrap: true to the ListView that's inside the column widget

Comment: I used 2 Scroll Inside column, first is horizontal and second is vertical ,and with these changes its scroll currect

Comment: Yes of course. Horizontal scroll has no connection to this one.. For vertical scroll you have to add the same controller that you add it to the draggablescrallablesheet.. I mean it will share the same scroll controller.. Both vertical scroll and DraggableScrollableSheet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73240554/flutter-scroll-list-over-header

Comment: Please pass the controller that you have in builder of DraggableScrollableSheet to the list view and assign this controller to the list view

Comment: I did it check my codes plz, it dosent right

Comment: OK,now is so better , but i want the top part of my Column with the borders stay on top Like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzRUD.png

Comment: Then remove the single child and use only the ListView. remove physics from list view too.