# Flutter DraggableScrollableSheet Lock One Part on top

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I Had Question For how create Scroll List Like this

[Flutter Scroll List Over Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73240554/flutter-scroll-list-over-header/73240761?noredirect=1#comment129358415_73240761)

[image]  [image]

According to the answers given, I used `DraggableScrollableSheet` for implementing this scroll view

but now i have new problem

The Result is here:

[image]

now I need to when im scrolling the top Child Stay On Top, like a header

[image]

how can do this?

Here is my Code

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    AppController appController = Provider.of<AppController>(context);
    HomeController homeController = Provider.of<HomeController>(context);
    String selectedCategory = homeController.selectedCategory;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        //height: 450,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/home_header.png'),
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        )),
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
            flexibleSpace: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
              child: ChiscoAppbar(
                icon: MENU,
                iconAlignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                title: 'خانه',
                onClick: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/account');
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  height: 200,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      const Expanded(
                        flex: 3,
                        child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: ChiscoText(
                              text: 'دستگاه‌های هوشمند چیسکو',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16,
                            )),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: const [
                                HeaderItem(
                                  titleText: 'کنترلر',
                                  icon: COOLER,
                                  counterText: '2',
                                ),
                                HeaderItem(
                                  titleText: 'سه راهی',
                                  icon: SOCKET,
                                  counterText: '2',
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          )),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
                  expand: true,
                  minChildSize: 0.70,
                  maxChildSize: 0.95,
                  initialChildSize: 0.70,
                  builder: (context, scrollController) {
                    return SingleChildScrollView(
                      controller: scrollController,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue[100],
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                                topRight: Radius.circular(25))),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            ListHandlerView(),
                            Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 8, 20, 10),
                              height: 30,
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                  itemCount: appController
                                      .listOfDevicesCategory.length,
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  primary: true,
                                  addSemanticIndexes: false,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    String category = appController
                                        .listOfDevicesCategory[index];
                                    return CategoryListItem(
                                      isSelected: selectedCategory == category,
                                      category: category,
                                    );
                                  }),
                            ),
                            ListView.builder(
                              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemCount: 25,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          floatingActionButton: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
              child: const ChiscoSpeedDial()),
          floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.startDocked,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better if you use App Bar bottom,

Comment: You can check your last question,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to use `bottom` from `SliverAppBar`. Run below widget to see the result

```dart
class DAX extends StatefulWidget {
  DAX({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DAX> createState() => _DAXState();
}

class _DAXState extends State<DAX> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 200,
              pinned: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              elevation: 0,
              bottom: PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60),
                  child: ColoredBox(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Container(
                      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(12),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        child: Row(
                          children: List.generate(
                            12,
                            (index) => Chip(
                              label: Text("chip $index"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) => Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: 100,
                  child: Text("$index"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can i Handle The Top Part of horizontal list , The Gray Small Container

Comment: I am using Row with  `SingleChildScrollView` if you are talking about sizing, increase `preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60),` or also can have decoration on container